# Update chart border color with plotband color in angular gauge

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I have a highchart for gauge as below :

```
$('#div1').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        borderColor:'#EBBA95',
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    title: {
        text: 'demo'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,

        minorTickInterval: '',

        tickPixelInterval: 15,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 50,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 50,
            to: 80,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 80,
            to: 100,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'series1',
        data: [100],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
    }]

});
```

Now I want to update the border color of a chart with series data plot band color. As here we have data as 100 and its plot band color is red ,the chart border color should be red. How can I get plot band color ?

Initially it will be different color . I want to update the color depending on the plot band color for the tool tip of the gauge . In the above image it is 186 so the color shoulb be red.If it falls under 0-120 category then the border color should be green.

Comment: _chart border color should be red_  can you update with picture, what you want

Comment: Chart border color should be updated with plot band color. I have added the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put proper red color in chat options

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gpdaeug/1/)

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'gauge',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBackgroundImage: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,
    borderColor:'#DF5353', /*red color*/
    borderWidth: 2
},
```

**Update**

After getting what OP wants

using `events` `load` option you can get changed border color based on date value in series

[Update fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6gpdaeug/3/)

Test it by changing the data value in series

```
      events: {
    load: function() {
      var series_data = this.series[0].data; //this is  series data
      for (var i = 0; i < series_data.length; i++) {

        if (series_data[i].y >= 0 && series_data[i].y <= 120) {
          this.update({
            chart: {
              borderColor: "#55BF3B"
            },
          });
        }
        if (series_data[i].y > 120 && series_data[i].y <= 160) {
          this.update({
            chart: {
              borderColor: "#DDDF0D"
            },
          });
        }
        if (series_data[i].y > 160 && series_data[i].y <= 200) {
          this.update({
            chart: {
              borderColor: "#DF5353"
            },
          });

        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Initially it will be different color . I want to update the color depending on the plot band color for the tool tip of the gauge . In the above image it is 186 so the color shoulb be red.If it falls under 0-120 category then the border color should be green.

Comment: ok i got it, you want the border color will be according to the inner pointer

Comment: image range markers are different from the code you provided. so updated the answer